# WP_Object_Cache for heavy WP_Query

Tags: cache, customization

I am wondering what is the best way to cache a Wp_Query that can have from 10 items to 10000.
I know it's a bad practice but for specific reason I have to process all this post types all together and depends on the installation the volume of the items.

Looking on https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache seems that I can cache pretty easily but I wondering if save the output of Wp_Query (after parsing) using this method is a good solution because for this edge case.

Actually I cache this parsing in the class in a variable to avoid multiple execution, but keep this cache between different calls to the website will be not a bad idea.

Comment: WP_Object_Cache won't help because it only stores data for the life of the request. It sounds like you want a [Transient](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API).

Comment: @JacobPeattie Yes and no. WP_Object_Cache can be used for persistent object caching with `wp-content/object-cache.php` drop-in and an object cache backend (memcached/redis/etc).

Comment: Well yeah, if you *add* functionality that does that sure, but on its own WP_Object_Cache is not persistent.

Comment: wp object cache is not persistent by default, wp transients api is. This may be what you are looking for.

Comment: You really shouldn‘t store the whole query in the cache.. Store either the resulting post IDs or post objects.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I think that I will try with a daily transient to store the output of wp_query parsed. Maybe also implement a system that clean up the transient only when required by the plugin itself. In case of a persistent object-cache I will use that (check if the file exist).